# Существуют ли бесплатные аналоги API Edmunds?

Tags: база-данных, поиск-api, auto

интересует есть ли в бесплатном доступе базы данных автомобилей содержащих: марки, модели и остальные характеристики, пишу дипломную работу на тему автомобильного маркетплейса.

Пробовал искать open API, но это не увенчалось успехом

Comment: Надо именно API? Если не получится найти, то можешь сам парсить сайт какой-нибудь...

Comment: не обязательно апи